# How to add fields in Drupal Registration Form?

Tags: users

I have installed content profile module. I just want some fields in drupal sign up page. I am using Drupal 6. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After you have enabled the module there will be a new content type called Profile available. Add fields to the content type Profile under admin/content/types.

The fields you add here will show up when the user registers.

Answer (score 1):

Select `Use this content type as a content profile for users` option under your `admin/content/node-type/profile` page. After that go to `admin/content/node-type/profile/profile` and the option `Hide form fields` elements is there to show only few fields on registration page.